# No funciona mi carrito de compras con JS

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras y al tocar el boton agregar al carrito me tira este error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild'), y no se me agrega al archivo HTML5 donde esta el carrito. pero si lo pongo para que se agregue a la consola si se agrega.
Estuve averiguando y todos lo hacen en el mismo archivo HTML5 pero yo al intentarlo en otro archivos me tira error

```
CODIGO DEL CARRITO

    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="carrito-contenedor"></div>
        </section>
        <script src="funcionMujer.js"></script>
        <script src="funcionHombre.js"></script>
        <script src="stockMujer.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    CODIGO DEL CATALOGO
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="topAdore">
            </div>
        </section>
        <a href="carrito.html">carrito</a>
        <script src="stockMujer.js"></script>
        <script src="funcionMujer.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    CODIGO JS
JavaScript
    let contenedorCarrito = document.getElementsByClassName('carrito-contenedor')
    
    let carrito = []
    
    const agregarAlCarrito = (prodId) =>{
        const item = stockProductos.find((prod) => prod.id === prodId)
        carrito.push(item)
        actualizarCarrito()
        console.log(carrito)
    }
    
    const actualizarCarrito = () => {
    
        carrito.forEach((prod) =>{
            const div = document.createElement('div')
            div.classList.add('productoEnCarrito')
            div.innerHTML = `
            <p>${prod.nombre}</p>
            <p>Precio: ${prod.precio}</p>
            <p>Cantidad: <span id="cantidad">${prod.cantidad}</span></p>
            <button onclick = "eliminarDelCarrito(${prod.id})" class="boton-eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></button
            `
            contenedorCarrito.appendChild(div)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que cuando declaras la variable *contenedorCarrito*, lo estás haciendo con *getElementsByClassName()* y ésto devuelve un array con TODOS los elementos que incluyen la clase *carrito-contenedor*. Tienes dos opciones para solucionarlo.

Añadir [0] al final de la declaración para obtener el primer elemento del array devuelto:

```
let contenedorCarrito = document.getElementsByClassName('carrito-contenedor')[0]
```

O, si solo vas a tener un elemento con la clase *carrito-contenedor*, también puedes cambiar la manera de declarar *contenedorCarrito* para usar un método que lo devuelva directamente:

```
// con querySelector()
let contenedorCarrito = document.querySelector('.carrito-contenedor')

// o con getElemenyById(), añadiendo el atributo 'id' con valor 'carrito-contenedor' al código HTML
let contenedorCarrito = document.getElementById('carrito-contenedor')
```

Comment: Ahora lo hice con querySelector y me tira este error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Comment: ¿Pusiste el punto en '.carrito-contenedor'?

Comment: si lo puse
`let contenedorCarrito = document.querySelector('.carrito-contenedor')`

Comment: He hecho una prueba aquí (creé un objeto stockProductos con la información que le pasas para poder hacerlo) y con querySelector me funciona bien. Completa la información de la pregunta con tu código HTML por si acaso. Mientras, prueba con las otras dos opciones indicadas.

Comment: el tema es que estas tratando de guardar dentro de un padre inexistente en este caso  `DIV` tendrías que crear un padre en la `DOM` que ya exista, o si no hacer referencia al `class` que le estas añadiendo al `div padre` que seria `producto`